# Visual Studio: Create a Hello World app in C?

Tags: c, visual-studio, ide

How can I create a basic C app in Visual Studio, be it 2010 Ultimate or 2008 Professional? I have searched through the project templates, and can find plenty for C++, but none for C.

(I'm hoping that the compiler and debugger will be built in.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio doesn't have a separate compiler for C, it uses the C++ compiler for C code.  You can tell it to restrict itself to legal C syntax by using a compiler switch or by renaming the .cpp file to .c

Edit: I'm still using 2005 on this machine, so it might not be in the same place, but try this

- Right click on the main.cpp in the solution explorer pane (on the right).
- Choose Properties (bottom of the menu)
- Open up the C/C++ group of properties
- choose Advanced page
- Change "Compile As" property to "Compile as C Code (/TC)"

Comment: What would that compiler switch be, and would I set it?

Comment: By default, it judges by extension. You can override that in the project properties.

Answer (score 6):

New project/Win32 Console Application/Empty project.

Add a file called "hello.c" (important that it's .c)

Type out a basic hello-world:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Compile, execute... PROFIT!

Comment: Your last words made me laugh!!! incidentally, someone posted a question asking would anyone be interested in a 'hello world' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168417/would-you-buy-a-hello-world-t-shirt-closed...now that's PROFIT!!! :) +1 from me...

Comment: Ha, you're not profiting yet, but maybe after you add a few more lines.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to changing the file extension, you may need to change the compiler settings:
Settintgs of Application->C/C++->addition->compiler such...
You must take /TC for basic C and /TP for C++.
`https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/032xwy55.aspx`
Good Luck.