# how program in ANSI C applying Visual Studio 2015 (as editor & compiler)?

Tags: c

I'm just start to study C programming language. I was recommended to use Visual Studio 2015 as modern editor and compiler. Can it work for just C?

Comment: _"Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."_

Comment: I would go for gcc-based toolchain with some nice IDE..

Comment: Code::Blocks and GCC (starting with v5) will be a very good choice.

Comment: @SouravGhosh The question is pointed. There is no degree of opinion. Obviously any question can be interpreted and this question has already been misinterpreted based on previous comments.

Comment: Re the specific question: yes, you can use it just for C programs. It can be used either as IDE or as command line tool. I recommend trying to use it "out of the box", which will be IDE. Free downloadable Express version is available.

Comment: @nicomp Then what is "how to start programming in C using Visual Studio 2015?"

Comment: @nicomp also, "Can it work" is a bit too broad, IMHO.

Comment: VS will probably fulfil most of your C needs, provided you stick to C89/90. Later versions (C99, C11) weren't fully implemented last I checked. Instead, you'd have to use either C++ or the near-C subset that C++ offers. If you want to write only C, and benefit from all of the C99/11 goodies, gcc would be the better choice

Comment: @SouravGhosh "Can it work" is not broad in this context. The OP says "I'm just start to study C programming language." : in that context the answer is "yes."  There is no ambiguity.

Comment: This link can help-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170169/visual-studio-create-a-hello-world-app-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Visual Studio can be used for just C. You can create a project that will compile C code and produce an executable program.

See http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/tali/E15/Visual_C.html for a short explanation of how to create a simple project and write C code in VS.

Comment: Thanks a lot - your answer was just what needed.

Comment: Hyperlink is dead - please revise

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is **yes** it can. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Supported_products) for more details, and other languages that are supported.

However, many start programming in C without an IDE. Although, it can help you troubleshoot syntactical errors, you'll find that its most likely going to get in the way.

If you're new to programming; C is a great language to start with. I would recommend watching [CS50](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zFenJJtAEzE&list=PLhQjrBD2T383Xfn0zECHrOTpfOSlptPAB). Happy programming.